# Bug Fileupload ASP.NET in safari (ipad) in first time

Tags: asp.net, safari

I'm writing a upload screen by ASP.NET. I tested successfull on website and Chorome(Ipad). But in Safari(ipad 9.0.2) have a problem:
- When I chose a file then click upload button => Have error request link. Then I refresh and upload again with upload successfull.
This is my code:
DetailView.Aspx:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
   <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
   <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>

protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteLog logWriterOCWStart = new WriteLog("PhucVV", loginId, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Web.config:

```
<location path="FormCost/DetailView.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I use debug but it don't go to function UploadButton_Click (). So I don't know why it have this error.

Comment: Means your button click event not working. right??

Comment: Yes. button click only working in second and ...... time. Not working at first time.

Comment: Remove your existing button click event and regenerate again.

Comment: I want when I click button will upload my file. If I remove this button, I can't write this function.